# Divergence theorem of product

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, divergence-operator

Len $\Omega$ be bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with smooth boundary, $f$ smooth vector field on $\Omega$ with $f=0$ on $\partial \Omega$. How to use divergence theorem for $\displaystyle\int_{\Omega} (\textrm{div}\ f)^2 d^3\textbf{r}$ ? Thanks

Comment: You **can't** use the divergence theorem without more information on f.  Is it continuous?  Is it differentiable?

Comment: @user247327 Now it is okay.

Comment: The problem is very weird, I doubt an analytical solution, but a possible solution is that you can try to search a function $g: \Omega\to\mathbb{R}^3$ that $(\textrm{div}\ f)^2 =\textrm{div}\ g$. For use the divergence theorem.